# [antd]: Pagination and Table Not working?

Tags: javascript, antd

I'm on Antd vs.3.1.4.

I'm trying to position pagination on my table, but it's not working as copyable from the api/docs. Here are the props I'm setting:

```
<Table
   pagination={{ position: 'both' }}
   columns={columns}
   dataSource={appointmentTypes}
   rowKey="id"
/>
```

Here is the [rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njbUw.png)

just wondering what I'm doing wrong here? I took a look at the source code it should be correct. I'm passing in pagination props to their table, which should create the pagination element with all the passed props properties with _.extend.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Looks correct. Can you share the full js code?

Comment: should be working, restart your app... perhaps the changes have not been updated. This should be working.

Comment: not really much else to share here.. I am rendering Table by explicitly mapping out Columns though if that changes anything

Comment: on new discovery: pagination.position is the only prop that doesn't work for me. pagination.pageSize and pagination = false works.

Answer (score 1):

Just try it like that ..

change  the name position to pageSize

```
 <Table pagination={{ pageSize: 10 }}  columns={columns} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set unique rowKey per row, otherwise react will reuse old rows, such
that it looks like pagination is not working. something like this should do the trick

```js
rowKey={record => record.id}
```